# Why 'Res' Variable holding some Random numbers instead of retrieving the number from edit text field?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Below is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements           
View.OnClickListener {

private TextView TvTtlCrd;


    int Res = TvTtlCrd.getText().length();
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnCal:
            try {
                Float Calculation = (
                                   (Float.parseFloat(numM1) * Float.parseFloat(numP1))
                                    +(Float.parseFloat(numM2)*Float.parseFloat(numP2)));
                Float Result=Calculation/Res;
                TvRes.setText(String.valueOf(Result));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                TvRes.setText("Make sure to Enter all the fields");
            }
            break;
          }
      }
    }
```

When I debug the code I found that all variables retrieve the same number as in text field but the TvTtlCrd text field value is not retrieved. What is the reason?
I have posted only part of the code which is relevant.
also How to Store variables in List and calculate using list functions?
Thanks

Comment: `int Res = TvTtlCrd.getText().length();` - You're getting the `length()` of the text in `TvTtlCrd`, not the actual text, which you'd get with `toString()`. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: No, for the function Float Result=Calculation/Res; If i convert the res datatype to string it shows error message as operator '/' cannot be applied to J.L.float to J.L.String. I want to divide the Calculation result from the value mentioned in Res variable.

Comment: Your question says "the TvTtlCrd text field value is not retrieved. What is the reason?" That's the reason. The `length()` method returns the number of characters in the text, not the actual text itself. You need to get the text as a `String`, and convert it to a number, just like you are when you use `Float.parseFloat()` in the code below that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, It Worked. cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are grabbing the length of the TvTtlCrd Object instead of the Text.

Change:

```
int Res = TvTtlCrd.getText().length();
```

To:

```
int Res = Integer.parseInt(TvTtlCrd.getText().toString());
```

Or: and parse however you see fit to get the int value.

```
String Res = TvTtlCrd.getText().toString();
```

Comment: make sure to accept the solution so this thread gets resolved.